# request.onprogress not doing anything

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Hi all i am working with XMLHttpRequest and I am having issues, where when the request is being sent I want their to be a Loading.. tag to appear on the submit button, but while the form is being submitted nothing happens, this is making users want to click the button a second time which has caused the form to submit twice. 
is there a better way of doing this? Or am I doing it incorrectly? Below is my code.

```
var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('post', 'php/functions.php', true);
             request.onload = function(){
                 var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
             document.getElementById("formSubmit").disabled = false;
                 if(data.result == 'true' ){
                     $('formSubmit').set('html', 'Submit');
                    alert('Form has been submitted!');
                    resetReport();
                 }else{
                    alert('Error! Not able to submit form.');
                    $('errorSpan').set('html', data.errMsg);

                 }
            };
            request.onprogress = function(){
                $('formSubmit').set('html', 'Loading...');
             document.getElementById("formSubmit").disabled = true;

            };
            request.onerror = function(){
             document.getElementById("formSubmit").disabled = false;
                alert('Processing Error. Try again later');
            };
request.send(formData);
```

Comment: you can disable the button when sending the request and re-enable it when it is completed. Another this is that you should set the event handlers before the `.send`

Comment: i had disabled the button before but it was not working anyways.I am going to try putting them before the .send. that might be the issue

Comment: Hi there @GabrielePetrioli I tried doing what you mentioned posting the .send() at the bottom and it still isn't doing anything. My buttons are not disabling. I updated the code above to show the changes

Comment: are you using a framework ? what is `$('formSubmit').set` ?

Comment: oh yes, sorry i am using mootools libraries, but I also use regular JS for some things that are not included in the mootools libraries.

Comment: Is the line setting the html to "Loading..." working ? do you see the html change ? because if that line causes an error then the next line setting the `disabled` to `true` would not run. Do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: No, none. Interestingly enough I did a simple console.log() and after I got the  alert('Form has been submitted!'); for the onload, I saw the message I had put in the onprogress() appear. Could they be happening simultaneously?

Comment: finally are you sure that the request is not finishing instantly and so the disable enable happen so fast you do not see it ?

Comment: Oh wait! Do you suggest I enable the button after the resetReport() occurs? it's possible you are correct, and I am submitting twice because I am clicking the button when the form is submitting but before it resets. So it might be happening too fast, but the button is enabled before I can clear it.